# adb logcat -c prints "ioctl: Operation not permitted"

Tags: android, c, adb, logcat, android-logcat

Running `adb logcat -c` echoes `ioctl: Operation not permitted`

Though I get an error (if you could even call it that), **the logs are being cleared**.

I ran `strace` but can't seem to find any call to `ioctl`.

At the very end, I see:

```
read(3, "ioctl: Operation not permitted\r\n", 4096) = 32
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=18650, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffff768e000
write(1, "ioctl: Operation not permitted\r\n", 32ioctl: Operation not permitted^M
```

1. Why is `ioctl` failing? *Note* - `sudo` changes nothing.
2. Where is `ioctl` being called? Am I not interpreting the `strace` correctly? *Note* - tracing child processes changes nothing.
3. What's with the `^M` business? I've run into that guy before when copying files from Windows to Linux. I believe it's how vim encodes the carriage return. But why is it here? And only in that one place?

As I look over my question, I notice two things.

1. It's reading the ioctl error from somewhere. So does that mean it's not calling it? It just reads from a buffer and prints it (or more accurately, reads from a file into a buffer and writes the buffer contents to `stdout`)? Maybe the error is hard-coded and based on some condition - `if(error) printf("%s\n", ioctlerr);`.
2. It's printing `\r` which explains the `^M`. But why is there a `\r` in the first place. Porting issue?

What I didn't notice before is that `ioctl: Operation not permitted^M` is there because I'm sending stderr *and* stdout to this file, so the `^M` is a result of `adb logcat` not `strace`.

Comment: Note that it is `write(1, ...)`, so interestingly enough, the error gets written to `stdout`.

Comment: Right. The `ioctl` error is related to `adb logcat` which logs to `stdout` not `strace` which logs to `stderr`.

Comment: @dhke Perhaps I misunderstand your point. What do you find interesting about that? Is writing to `stdout` (in this context) unexpected behavior?

Comment: adb in my experience is quite consistent about writing its own errors to `stderr`. Even more so since the `ioctl:` looks like it is generated from  `perror()`. I'm guessing, but that this may be a device side error (from `adbd`) that just gets printed by the adb client.